# rewrite cause multi render on nextjs

Tags: next.js

I realized that Rewrite cause multi render on my nextjs project...
I try a lot of research but couldnt find much data about that..
There was just and answer that says "that is normal behaviour" but it wasnt approved

is it normal or I have to handle that problem?

Here is my next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: true,
  trailingSlash: true,
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {source: "/dashboard",      destination: "/loginpages/dashboard"},
      {source: "/features",       destination: "/logoutpages/features"},
      {source: "/solutions",      destination: "/logoutpages/solutions"},
      {source: "/plans",          destination: "/logoutpages/plans"},
      {source: "/pricing",        destination: "/logoutpages/pricing"},
      {source: "/about",          destination: "/logoutpages/about"},
      {source: "/cookies",        destination: "/logoutpages/cookies"},
      {source: "/policy",         destination: "/logoutpages/policy"},
      {source: "/terms",          destination: "/logoutpages/terms"},
      {source: "/apps",           destination: "/logoutpages/apps"},
      {source: "/contact",        destination: "/logoutpages/contact"},
      {source: "/login",          destination: "/auth/login"},
      {source: "/register",       destination: "/auth/register"},
    ];
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: It might be due to Automatic Static Optimization and the fact that Next.js triggers a re-render to provide the route parameters in the query object. Rewrites will trigger a re-render after hydration due to it. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization#how-it-works.

Comment: you mean it is normal?

Comment: If your pages are being statically optimised (no `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps`), then yes - it is normal.

Comment: I mean do I need to fix it.. or no need to fix?

Comment: I use  nodejs as backend not nextjs itself so no have serverside or initialpros I have